# How to block based on request content to a specific file?

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I've tried many times, I've added them all in order below, but I couldn't get any results. Where am I doing wrong?

First attempt

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@endsWith /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" \
        "id:1001, \
        deny, \
        t:none, \
        tag: 'Admin ajax post Silderz', chain"
        SecRule REQUEST_BODY "@rx Silderz"
```

Second attempt

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "^/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$" \
        "id:1001, \
        deny, \
        t:none, \
        tag: 'Admin ajax post Silderz', chain"
        SecRule REQUEST_BODY "action=Silderz\&nonce=\w{1,}"
```

Third attempt

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "^/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$" \
        "id:1001, \
        deny, \
        t:none, \
        tag: 'Admin ajax post Silderz', chain"
        SecRule REQUEST_BODY "^action=Silderz\&nonce=\w{1,}$"
```

This is outgoing FormData request;

```
action: 
Silderz
nonce: 
4e2cad2579
```

AND
Request Headers;

```
:authority: www.bursterksed.com
:method: POST
:path: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,az;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4,ru;q=0.3,pt;q=0.2,hu;q=0.1
content-length: 34
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
.......
.......
.......
```

Comment: CRS Dev-On-Duty here. I tested your first rule and it works for me. I had to delete the space after the `tag:`. But the rule should work. I put the 4 lines of your content into a file named data and used curl to test: `curl -vd @data http://localhost:80/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Could you share your ModSecurity settings? And are you maybe able to test it with HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because I didn't specify the phase state. "phase:2" => REQUEST_BODY

The following rule set works fine.

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@endsWith /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" \
        "id:1001, \
        phase:2, \
        deny, \
        nolog, \
        t:none, \
        tag: 'Admin ajax post Silderz', chain"
        SecRule ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|REQUEST_BODY|REQUEST_HEADERS|XML "@rx ^action=Silderz\&nonce=\w{1,}" "t:lowercase"
```

Comment: The directive SecDefaultAction is setting phase:2 by default, see here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#secdefaultaction. But maybe that was the difference here.